# AngularJS & UI Router : Why do $state.go() and $location.path() not work in interactive console?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

See this plunker : https://run.plnkr.co/mTN6nIsUkxFtiZLx/#/state1

https://plnkr.co/edit/KYQG3OMPoCthEDcus12Y?p=info

It's basically the demo code presented on UI Router documentation. To test navigation between states programmatically I made controller functions that use `$state.go(stateName)` and `$location.path(stateUrl)`, they both work fine.

The code of the controller :

```
myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$state', '$location',  function($scope, $state, $location) {
  $scope.usingState = function() {
    console.log('usingState() called');
    $state.go('state2');
  };
  $scope.usingLocation = function() {
    console.log('usingLocation() called');
    $location.path('/state2');
  };
}]);
```

However, in the interactive console (developper tools) it doesn't work. If I do the following :

```
$state = angular.element(document).injector().get('$state');
$state.go('state2');
```

or

```
$location = angular.element(document).injector().get('$location');
$location.path('/state2');
```

Nothing happens. Why ?

I would like to be able to make quick tests in the interactive console…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code which you mentioned seems to be working from console. In plunker you cannot get `injector` object from document since plunker runs code inside `<iframe>` where it loads angular.

To test functionality open UI router [Sample App](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/). Enter below code in console and observe state transition:

```
angular.element(document).injector().get('$state').go('about');
```

**UPDATE:**

In the plunker which you have provided, I have changed the angular version **1.1.5** to **1.2.0**(version released after **1.1.5**) and everything seems to be working fine. Here are the changelogs for [**1.2.0-rc.3**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#120-rc3-ferocious-twitch-2013-10-14) and [**1.2.0**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#120-timely-delivery-2013-11-08) which might help you track down why it didn't work in previous version.

[Updated Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Lmp5Z4oCbqeE59KA7JuF?p=preview). Hope this helps!

Comment: I use the functionality "lauch the preview in a separate window", which does not use iframe. I actually get the injector fine, just doing `angular.element(document).injector().get('$state')` gives me the $state service. BTW I got the problem on my machine, just reproduced it in plunker to show.

Comment: @Quentin Updated answer!